# how to reduce multiple OR conditions in if statement in c language

Tags: c

For this code I am getting "Function has a complexity of 48 which is greater than 20 authorized." How do i reduce the complexity?

```
void print_element_int_to_buf(p_printbuffer buf, const char *tag, int value, int mandatory)
#else
static void print_element_int_to_buf(p_printbuffer buf, const char *tag, int value, int mandatory)
#endif
{
        if(strcmp(tag,"probableCause") == 0){
                if((value >=0 && value <= 20)||(value >= 51 && value <= 70)||(value >= 81 && value <= 82)||(value >= 101 && value <= 133)||(value >= 151 && value <= 158)||(value >= 301 && value <= 303)||(value >= 305 && value <= 308)||(value >= 310 && value <= 311)||(value >= 315 && value <= 317)||(value >= 321 && value <= 327) ||(value >= 332 && value <= 334)||(value >= 339 && value <= 340)||(value >= 342 && value <= 348)||(value >= 350 && value <= 354)||(value >= 356 && value <= 357)||(value >= 501 && value <= 552)||(value >= 561 && value <= 593)||(value >= 701 && value <= 709)||(value >= 711 && value <= 718)||(value >= 1000 && value <= 1065)){
                        bufprintf(buf, "<%s>", tag);
                        bufprintf(buf, "%i", value);
                        bufprintf(buf, "</%s>", tag);
                        bufprintf(buf, "\n");
                }
                else if((value == 136 || value == 203 || value == 313 || value ==330 || value == 336)){
                        bufprintf(buf, "<%s>", tag);
                        bufprintf(buf, "%i", value);
                        bufprintf(buf, "</%s>", tag);
                        bufprintf(buf, "\n");
                }
                else{}
        }
        else{
                if(value != 0){  /* OSS_FC_013378_US_4370787_US_4745111: Schema validation using libxml2 for FM */
                        bufprintf(buf, "<%s>", tag);
                        bufprintf(buf, "%i", value);
                        bufprintf(buf, "</%s>", tag);
                        bufprintf(buf, "\n");
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Define 2 arrays of values and check them with a loop.

Comment: `else{}` is singularly pointless!

Comment: Am I misreading it or all the conditional bodies have the same statements?

Comment: Am I misreading it or is there one more `}` than there is `{`?  The indentation is a bit erratic. The long line is preposterous — split it across multiple lines.

Comment: If you are using GCC, case ranges (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html) can help you to make code more readable

Comment: You can use hashset to put all ranged values inside that, and use that to check if the value is contained in that hashset or not, because checking value in hashset will take O(n), and adding range in hash set will take O(n), but add range in hashset for once only, may be in static block

Answer (score 1):

Use a table to test the ranges, both multi-number ranges and singleton ranges, like this:

```
struct range
{
    int lo;
    int hi;
};

static const struct range ranges[] =
{
    {    0,   20 },
    {   51,   70 },
    {   81,   82 },
    {  101,  133 },
    {  136,  136 },     /* Singleton */
    {  151,  158 },
    {  203,  203 },     /* Singleton */
    {  301,  303 },
    {  305,  308 },
    {  310,  311 },
    {  313,  313 },     /* Singleton */
    {  315,  317 },
    {  321,  327 },
    {  330,  330 },     /* Singleton */
    {  332,  334 },
    {  336,  336 },     /* Singleton */
    {  339,  340 },
    {  342,  348 },
    {  350,  354 },
    {  356,  357 },
    {  501,  552 },
    {  561,  593 },
    {  701,  709 },
    {  711,  718 },
    { 1000, 1065 },
};
enum { NUM_RANGES = sizeof(ranges) / sizeof(ranges[0]) };

extern void bufprintf(p_printbuffer buf, const char *tag, ...);

static void print_tag_value(p_printbuffer buf, const char *tag, int value)
{
    bufprintf(buf, "<%s>", tag);
    bufprintf(buf, "%i", value);
    bufprintf(buf, "</%s>", tag);
    bufprintf(buf, "\n");
}

static void print_element_int_to_buf(p_printbuffer buf, const char *tag, int value)
{
    if (strcmp(tag, "probableCause") == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RANGES; i++)
        {
            if (value >= ranges[i].lo && value <= ranges[i].hi)
            {
                print_tag_value(buf, tag, value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (value != 0)
    {
        print_tag_value(buf, tag, value);
    }
}
```

If `bufprintf()` is a specialized version of `printf()`, it may be possible to reduce the sequence of 4 calls down to one call.  The question was updated to give the interface to `print_element_int_to_buf()` function.  It includes an unused parameter `mandatory`, which I've left out in my revised function.  I've used that information to give a plausible prototype for the `bufprintf()` function.

Comment: hey jonathan..i have included the function name as well.can you see if you can dig up something out of it?

Comment: I've updated the answer to more or less accommodate the information in your revised question.

Comment: everything seems fine.but why are we using enum here?

Comment: Because I like using `enum` for this job.  You're not obliged to use it, but it has advantages for debugging.  What would you use instead?